# How can I create a plugin in guidewire?

Tags: plugins, guidewire

I can't find de main steps to create a plugin in guidewire.
¿Is there any simple way to understand that?
Until now I did this steps

Modify the messaging-config.xml
Create a class in gosu to use the plugin
Create the plugin

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether you want to create a new plugin like a new custom functionality plugin or utilize Transport/Reply Plugin for a message destination.

If you want to implement a new custom plugin, then there are several steps as listed below.

1. Create Plugin class
2. Implement the interfaces
3. Implement code for the methods
4. Create plugin registry file.
5. Configure registry file
6. Deploy.

If you just want to learn how to do it, there is a detailed video available if you have access to a GW learning account.